What are options for sending emails via Kivy?
In my app I used to send emails via Gmail smtp, but that option has been disabled by Google, as I only discovered this morning while getting my app finished. What are my other options? I know of Yahoo, I tried registering an account but that's giving a known error too: "Too many attempts". Might try later, but in the meantime,
What other options do I have to send an email via my app? It's kind of an integral part of my app, so any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Set up your own mail server.

Have a look at this question.

This function is working and m using currently
import smtplib
import ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage

def send_email(body, email_receiver):
    # Email subject
    subject = 'Validation'

    # Gmail SMTP server settings
    smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    smtp_port = 587

    # Gmail account credentials
    email_sender = 'example@gmail.com'
    email_password = 'xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx'

    email_receiver = 'receiver@gmail.com'
    subject = 'Validation'
    body = 'testing 6digit'
    em = EmailMessage()
    em['From'] = email_sender
    em['To'] = email_receiver
    em['subject'] = subject
    em.set_content(body)
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as smtp:
        smtp.login(email_sender, email_password)
        smtp.sendmail(email_sender, email_receiver, em.as_string())


This works for me, thanks. Dont have enough reputation to upvote.
